# Cannot install anything using apt-get

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies

When I try for example:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gparted is already the newest version (0.25.0-1).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpcap0.8 : Breaks: libpcap0.8:i386 (!= 1.7.4-2) but 1.4.0-2 is to be installed
 libpcap0.8:i386 : Breaks: libpcap0.8 (!= 1.4.0-2) but 1.7.4-2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

(Yes, I know, that GParted is already installed. It's just an example). Ubuntu tries to help me and suggests using `sudo apt-get -f install`. But when I try it:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpcap0.8:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpcap0.8:i386
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 110 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/121 kB of archives.
After this operation, 20,5 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 219902 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpcap0.8_1.7.4-2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libpcap0.8:i386 (1.7.4-2) over (1.4.0-2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpcap0.8_1.7.4-2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libpcap0.8/CREDITS.gz', which is different from other instances of package libpcap0.8:i386
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpcap0.8_1.7.4-2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you haven't completely installed 2 packages...
Maybe

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Will do the job for you

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered problems like this only a few times and each time I was able to fix it simply by opening **Software & Updates** and on the first tab **Ubuntu Software** switch **Download from** (for example Server for United States). After closing and choosing to reload the software source list (asked when closing **Software & Updates**) it just worked again.

Probably a corrupted software source list that is fixed simply by switching server. Might be worth a try and can be changed (and changed back) without any risk.

Good luck!